Characterization of the RKHS
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a RKHS on $\mathcal{X}$ with reproducing kernel $K$, and let $f: \mathcal X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Why are the two following equivalent ?

$f\in\mathcal{H}$

There exists $c > 0$ such that the function $(x, y) \mapsto cK(x, y) - f(x)f(y)$ is a positive definite kernel function (i.e. symmetric, and such that $\sum\limits_{i, j} a_ia_j (cK(x_i, x_j) - f(x_i)f(x_j)) \geq 0$ for any $n\geq0, x_1, \dots, x_n \in \mathcal{X}, a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$).


I see why the first implies the second, but I do not see how to prove the converse.
Thank you for your help.

How do you define a kernel function?

I edited my initial question to answer your question. Thanks !
